# Two nested for of for and map?

Tags: dictionary, for-loop, clojure, idioms

When I need to generate a sequence which needs "two loops", is it better to do something like this:

```
(for [x (range 1 4)] (map #(* x %) (range 6 9)))
```

or something like this:

```
(for [x (range 1 4)] (for [y (range 6 9)] (* x y)))
```

Both give the same result:

```
((6 7 8) (12 14 16) (18 21 24))
```

Is one more idiomatic than the other and what are the differences between these two?

Also, is it possible to get the same result by nesting two *map*?

Answer (score 8):

Either is fine, but the second version scales better to arbitrary nesting levels.

Nesting `map` calls works, too:

```
user=> (map (fn [x] (map (fn [y] (* x y)) (range 6 9))) (range 1 4))
((6 7 8) (12 14 16) (18 21 24))
```

You cannot nest the shortcut function syntax, though.

By the way, just in case you actually need more set-comprehension-like semantics, `for` also has nesting built-in.  The result is somewhat different:

```
user=> (for [x (range 1 4), y (range 6 9)] (* x y))
(6 7 8 12 14 16 18 21 24)
```

Comment: +1...  Regarding the built-in nesting: I was indeed doing two nested loops and then a *flatten* to get a single sequence (instead of a sequence of sequences).  I get it now: I was trying to nest two *map* by using the #(...) shortcut, hence getting nowhere!

Answer (score 2):

Remember `for` in clojure isn't a 'loop', it's a list comprehension. I find it easier to think backwards from the required value, rather than forwards from how I iterate.

It seems you are trying to create a sequence of values where the value is

`(map #(* x %) y)`

- `x` is `1 >= x > 4`  => `(range 1 4)`
- `y`, is `(range 6 9)` => `(repeat (range 6 9))`

But since you want the comprehension to terminate, you need a tweak to `y` giving

- `y` -> `[(range 6 9)]`

finally as an idiomatic list comprehension (note this is very similar to your first example, so you were almost there)

```
(for [x (range 1 4) y [(range 6 9)]] (map #(* x %) y))
((6 7 8) (12 14 16) (18 21 24))
```